# Matlab to C++ code generation (hdf5 format)

Tags: c++, matlab, code-generation, hdf5

There is a Matlab function (h5write) that lets the user write output files in hdf5 format. This seems to work nicely when using the Matlab environment and Matlab files. However, when I try to generate C++ code out of the Matlab files, a conversion error arises. It appears that the code generator (Matlab Coder) cannot convert the h5write operation into C++ code.

Is there any way of getting around this issue? Efficiency is also important here since the data sets that need to be stored by the generated C++ executable are fairly large. If anybody could help me out here, it would make my day! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB currently provide an interface for converting the code for h5write into C++ code. That being said, you can use MATLAB compiler to build an executable or dll. You can use this in your C++ code, but you will always need the MCR. If space is not a constraint, you can do this.

Otherwise, you can use the HDF5 API (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/) and write code for writing into HDF5 file format and then use MATLAB Coder to link and compile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But which interface is that? And do you perhaps know why I get the conversion error at the h5write operation when I try generating the C++ code with the Matlab Coder?

Comment: I will answer the second part first. MATLAB Coder hasn't enabled code generation for this function as of the moment. Only this small subset is enabled [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html). However, if you want support, do contact technical support [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html), who will forward the request to the developers. To answer the first question, try using one of their examples [link](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/writedata_8cpp-example.html).